# Is it possible to use FindAllById in JPA with our custom Arguements

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am trying to retrieve set of records in DB that matches my query criteria. I am having Employee Collection in DB and i am trying to find out the details of List of Employees.

Below is my model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_table")
public class Employee {
@Id
private int id;
private String empName;
private String empId;
private String department;
//Getter, Setter
}
```

And below is my native query to retrieve employee data based on employee Id:
I want to retrieve details of more than one employee so i am passing employee id in list.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "SELECT empId FROM employee_table WHERE empId IN ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Employee> findAllByempId(List<String> empId);
```

The above native query is working fine and it is giving me the result but i want to know is there any better way to perform the required action like if i want to find a single employee based on Employee id then i can use JPA method findByEmpId("12345") and no need to write any native query likewise can i do for findAll also?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAll--

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: And why do you annotate your method with Modifying? This query doesn't modify anything. I think you really, really should read the documentation. It helps a lot. You should also learn JPQL instead of using native queries.

Comment: You should be used java configuration for providing a different query for the method as per requirements

Comment: CrudRepository#findById(id) can be used to get a single record of entity type.